# If $ax^2+bx+c$ has repeated root $x=r$, what is the condition number solving for $r$ if you only change one of $a,b,c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, quadratics, condition-number

I will edit to be specific like Shaun said:

> If $ax^2+bx+c$ has repeated root $x=r$, what is the condition number
>   solving for $r$ if you only change one of $a,b,c$?

The book says that if $r$ is a simple root that $\kappa= 1/f'(r)$ (but shouldn't this be constant?) but that if the root is repeated that this is ill conditioned but I get $\kappa= 1/(2\sqrt{r} + 2r)$, so how is this enough for it to be ill conditioned? Wouldn't this just be for $r=0$? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun Is that much better?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. It could be a little more specific though.

Comment: There are often multiple definitions of  condition number, which are related but not exactly the same. Also it looks like you may have quoted the textbook correctly, since that $\kappa$ isn't a constant, but rather a function of $x$.

Comment: @Shaun I hope that finally works